# StateFlow not Trigger Loading() when back from another activity

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-stateflow

**Situation**

Example I have 2 activities, `Activity Menu` and `Activity Detail`. Flow system is, I go to `Activity Menu`, click a button to `Activity Detail`. I updated the data from `Activity Detail`. When press Back Button at the phone, only `Resource Success` trigger, not the `Resource Loading`.

**Codes Relevant**

Resource class

```
sealed class Resource<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val message: String? = null,
    val messageInt: Int? = null,
    val code: Int? = null,
    val errorReader: Reader? = null,
) {
    class Initialize<T> : Resource<T>()
    class Loading<T>(data: T? = null) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Success<T>(data: T?) : Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(
        message: String? = null,
        messageInt: Int? = null,
        data: T? = null,
        code: Int? = null,
        errorReader: Reader? = null
    ) :
        Resource<T>(data, message, messageInt, code, errorReader)
}
```

At ViewModel

```
private val _itemList = MutableStateFlow<Resource<Int>>(Resource.Initialize())
val itemList: StateFlow<Resource<Int>> = _itemList

init {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        getItemList()
    }
}

suspend fun getItemList() = viewModelScope.launch {
    _itemList.emit(Resource.Loading())

    val data = withContext(ioDispatcher + coroutineExceptionHandler) {
        return@withContext quickSave.getInt(Constant.BROKEN_TOTE_LIST_COUNT, 0)
    }
    
    //Only this Success trigger for 2nd time
    _itemList.emit(Resource.Success(data = data))
}
```

At the Activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityToteBrokenBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val root = binding.root
    setContentView(root)

    startLifeCycle()
}

private fun startLifeCycle() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            launch {
                collectItemList()
            }
        }
    }
}

private suspend fun collectItemList() {
    viewModel.itemList.collectLatest {
        when (it) {
            is Resource.Initialize -> {
            }
            is Resource.Loading -> {
                Log.i("???","Resource Loading")
                showLoading()
            }
            is Resource.Success -> {
                Log.i("???","Resource Success")
                handleSuccess()
                hideLoading()
            }
            is Resource.Error -> {
                hideLoading()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Output

```
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (30051) for package com.company.com ----------------------------
2022-09-29 12:21:51.977 30051-30051 ???                     com.company.com                 I  Resource Loading
2022-09-29 12:21:52.137 30051-30051 ???                     com.company.com                 I  Resource Success
2022-09-29 12:22:10.839 30051-30051 ???                     com.company.com                 I  Resource Success
```

The Output not trigger `Resource Loading`. How to make it trigger again every time I back from the `Activity Detail`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First as in your `getItemList()` method you are already using `viewModelScope.launch`, you can remove the `suspend` modifier from it.

The 2nd time success is not getting triggered from your view model function but because you are using `lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED)` hence the flow is getting collected again after coming back to the activity.

So in your menu activity you can `override onResume` method, and in that you can call the view model function `getItemList()`, which will then emit in your expected sequence.

Only drawback is that it will get trigger on every onResume, even when Lock/Unlock happens or you are returning to the app from background.

Comment: Any other way to avoid using `onResume` ?

Comment: you can have a activity scoped view model where you can define a flag, which will be set when api reload is required, and then in your Activity Menu, you can read that flag, call the api and reset the flag for next usage